# TypeError: instance[method].bind is not a function AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, adonis.js

I am integrating MQTT-adonis module [adonis-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-mqtt) respo on git [here](https://github.com/Morlack/adonis-mqtt#readme) in `adonis-js` application while serving it throws an exception

> TypeError: instance[method].bind is not a function

Can any one guide why this is appearing.

**//event.js**

```
'use strict'
 const Event = use('Event');
const Mqtt = use('Mqtt');
// Listen to some Events of the library
Event.on('MQTT:Connected', 'Message.subscription')
Event.on('MQTT:Disconnected', 'Message.disconnected')
```

**//Listeners/Message.js**

```
class Message extends MqttListener {

get subscription () {
return 'Topic/Info'
 }

async handleMessage (message, wildcardMatches) {
  }
```

it appears that it is throwing exception here in this block

**//node_modules/adonis-mqtt/Mqtt/Mqtt.js**

```
this.client.on('connect', this._handleConnect.bind(this)) //here at this line
    this.client.on('offline', this._handleDisconnect.bind(this))
    this.client.on('close', this._handleDisconnect.bind(this))
    this.client.on('end', this._handleDisconnect.bind(this))
    this.client.on('message', this._handleMessage.bind(this))
```

> **EDIT:::**

**How to reproduce this:**

*pre-requisite:*

- Node JS latest version ([here](https://nodejs.org/en/))
- Adonis Js latest versions ([here](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/installation))

**clone this:**

- https://github.com/Q930844N/mqtt-adonis-test
- move to directory path
- `npm install`
- `adonis serve --dev`

**Update:**

while removing get from subscription function, it works with no error, but I am unable to get the required data in following code snippet

**//node_modules/adonis-mqtt/Mqtt/Mqtt.js**

```
async _registerListener (file) {
    const filePath = path.join(this.listenersPath, file)
    let task
    try {
      task = require(filePath)
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
        debug(
          'Unable to import task class <%s>. Is it a valid javascript class?',
          file)
        return
      } else {
        throw e
      }
    }

    // Get instance of task class
    const taskInstance = ioc.make(task)
    if (!taskInstance.subscription || taskInstance.subscription === '') {
      console.error(`MqttListener ${file} does not have a subscription string!`)
    } else {
      this.client.subscribe(taskInstance.subscription) // here
      debug('Subscribed to topic %s', taskInstance.subscription)
      console.log('Subscribed to topic %s', taskInstance.subscription)
      this.listeners.push(taskInstance)
    }
  }
```

**Update: 2**

There are two folders in app one is **Listeners** and other is **MqttListeners**, thse both have same named file `Test.js`, it is also forcing to keep both files. However changes in file exist in Listener folder doesnt make any impact. However removing get prefix from subscription function and console messages in `handleMessage()` from MqttListners folder's file is seems to be perfect. Receiving published topics info

Comment: Can you share the project? So I can try to reproduce the problem

Comment: @CrBast updated the question for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems is here

```
// events.js
Event.on('MQTT:Connected', 'Message.subscription')
```

By this, you're binding `Message.subscription` method to `MQTT:Connected` event (actually, this happens in node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js#L879).

However, your **`Message.subscription` is not a normal function but getter**. You cannot bind getters because this [method syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions) doesn't use function expressions.

So, in order to fix your problem you should either bind `MQTT:Connected` event to some other method i.e.

```
// events.js
Event.on('MQTT:Connected', 'Message.connection')

// Listeners/Message.js
class Message extends MqttListener {
  connection() {
     return 'test/#';
  }
}
```

or simply remove `get` prefix from your `subscription` method

```
// Listeners/Message.js
class Message extends MqttListener {

  subscription () {
    return 'test/#';
  }
}
```

Please let me know if my answer is not clear enough or you need some additional information.

UPDATE:
See some proof that it works
[image: Screenshot of the fix]

Comment: error gone. earlier mistakenly removed get from another class

Comment: Great. Let me know if any additional help required

Comment: yes I need. Now the mqtt is connected and subscribed all of topics as I have set it to #, how would I get the topic messages in my controller

Comment: something like this -- `Event.on('MQTT:onMessage', 'Test.handleMessage')`

Comment: As I understand (I'm not very familar with AdonisJS and mqtt module) and according to the docs (https://github.com/Morlack/adonis-mqtt/blob/HEAD/instructions.md#sending-messages) you can use whatever event name i.e. `Mqtt.sendMessage('mytopic', 'My Message', {qos: 1})` and handle it in similar manner `async handleMessage (message, wildcardMatches) {}` where the first argument is the message data. If you're using thirdparty service you should use their docs in order to get the messages name. I can help if you provide me with this information.

Comment: this subscription function is actually returning the topic names, provided in return, if I remove getter, I am unable to get topic names

Comment: here in this code snippet `this.client.subscribe(taskInstance.subscription)
      debug('Subscribed to topic %s', taskInstance.subscription)
      console.log('Subscribed to topic %s', taskInstance.subscription)
      this.listeners.push(taskInstance)` in this //node_modules/adonis-mqtt/Mqtt/Mqtt.js

Comment: you were also right.. there is a confusion in folders, two folders must exists with same file `Test.js`, one is `Listeners` and other is `MqttListners` should have `get` before `subscription`.

Comment: Yes, exactly mqtt listeners should be defined in `app/MqttListeners` and `subscription` is a special method used for defining [MQTT wildcard format](https://github.com/Morlack/adonis-mqtt/blob/HEAD/instructions.md#listeners). However, for handling messages you can use [simple adonis listeners](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/events#_events_overview) as you do now.

Comment: How can I pass data  to this subscription method, I want to pass user id with text, but I am unable to do.